# Changing domain name for free-electrons

Tags: discussion, broken-link

[Free Electrons becomes Bootlin](https://lwn.net/Articles/746345/), due to some overly litigious party, and while the old domain name redirects to the new one, depending on the outcome of the legal procedure, they may not be able to do that forever.

Now, there are [a lot of links to free-electrons on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*free-electrons.com%22), mainly due to their LXR instance. So, the question is, how do we deal with this? Could there be an automated way to deal with it?

Comment: It's pretty sad that their strategy actually worked and Free Electrons probably won't offer any opposition. Any company that cared would use a different name in France only, even if they lost the case.

Comment: Yeah, next step is to register ~26-30 companies, one letter in name and sue everyone who is using letters.

Comment: I bet that free-electrons.com will win against free.fr.

Comment: I think "Trademarking 'free'" is a contraction in terms.

Comment: i dont think its the communities job. its up to the 3rd party to make links wokr.

Comment: @DanielA.White actually, for Jon Skeet when he moved domains, SE did edit all the links to his blog.

Comment: @0andriy How come Free didn't sue FreeBSD yet?

Comment: @Cœur It's not really about whether they can win, it's about a small group of people trying to fight a juggernaut. It's financially impossible to even put up a decent fight. It's like getting a [SLAPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_lawsuit_against_public_participation), they often win solely based on the burden it puts on the defendant.

Comment: @Braiam [Jon Skeet links correct themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134), surely?

Comment: I wish the US embassy would have a little chat with the frenchies and say, "Don't be silly, you can't trademark a single, correctly spelled word, especially not in as broad of contexts as you seek to."

Comment: So it's the end of free software, free beer, free speech and free hugs too?

Comment: @Laf worse: the end of free electrons.